# Template class type-specific functions

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-function, template-classes

Ok, so i have this template class, which is kinda like one-way list.

```
template <typename T> List
```

and it have this inside function print

```
public:
void Print();
```

which, as you can guess, prints the list contents from begining to end;
However, as template can take classes as T, one can imagine, that i would need different implementations of Print() for that very cases. For example, I have another class Point

```
class Point{
 private:
  int x, y;
 public:
  int getX();
  int getY();
}
```

so i want Print specifically designed for Points. I tried this:

```
void List<Point>::Print();
```

but compiler tells me

```
prototype for void List<Point> Print() doesn match any in class List<Point>
```

though

```
candidates are: from List<T> [with T = Point] void List<Point>::Print()
```

For me it seems like the same fucntion. What's wrong? And how do I write T-specific template class functions?

Comment: `template<> void List<Point>::Print()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use [explicit template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) to specialize behaviour of `Print` for specific types.

For example, for `Point`:

```
template <> // No template arguments here !
void List<Point>::Print() // explicitly name what type to specialize
{
  //code for specific Point Print behaviour..
}
```

Comment: Does it goes in class body? Or outside of it?

Comment: @YuryElburikh Outside of it.

Comment: now it tells me that "no member function "Print" is declared in List<int>"

Comment: @YuryElburikh well an `int` is not a `Point`. You should still provide a fallback implementation for `Print` for the other cases.

Comment: And what if i only want Print for ints and Points?
I did

    'template<>    void List<int>::Point();'

    'template<>    void List<Point>::Print();'

Comment: @YuryElburikh You still need a fallback one that then does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> However, as template can take classes as T, one can imagine, that i would need different implementations of Print() for that very cases

Not at all. You can have a single implementation of `Print` for every type of object - this is why templates are powerful.

One way to do what you want would be to define the stream operator `<<` in `Point`, and have a generic `Print()` method in `List`. This makes `Print` available to more than just `Point`.

More generality ftw.

Comment: Hmm, this approach I like a whole lot more, however, for this project I have to use Point provided without any modifications to it